# is it true that $\mathcal A$ and $\sigma(\mathcal B,\mathcal C)$ are independent?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ be a probability space. Let $\mathcal A,\mathcal B,\mathcal C\subseteq \mathcal F$. If $\mathcal A,\mathcal B,\mathcal C$ are pairwise independent, is it true that $\mathcal A$ and $\sigma(\mathcal B,\mathcal C)$ are independent?

I tried to prove it by showing $\mathcal D:=\{
D\in\mathcal F:$ $A,D$ are independent for all $A\in\mathcal A\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal C$. But I don't think $\mathcal D$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Maybe you can try to construct an easy counter-example to disprove it.

Comment: @XiangxiangXu I strengthened the hypothesis.

Comment: Now the statement is false still. So there is a common counterexample to illustrate that pairwise independence does not imply independence of several events. Suppose you have $X, Y$ which are i.i.d. Bern(1/2), and let $Z = X \oplus Y$, that is, $Z = \mathbb{1}_{X \neq Y}$, indicating whether $X$ and $Y$ have different values or not. Now $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are pairwise independent, but $Z$ and $X + Y$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

Many texts on probability give you an example of events $A,B,C$ which are pairwise independent but not jointly independent. If you take $\mathcal A=\sigma(\{A\})$,$\mathcal B=\sigma(\{B\})$,$\mathcal C=\sigma(\{C\})$  you get a counter-example.